# How to load custom icon fonts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am giving Vue 2x a try by building a mini project. Now I want to add custom icon fonts download from flaticon.com. I generated the project using `vue-cli webpack`

In `webpack.base.conf.js` I have this

```
...
{
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
},
...
```

As with every other project, I use sass, which compiles well. So in my main sass file `app.scss` I added

```
...
@font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon";
    src: url("./assets/fonts/Flaticon.eot");
    src: url("./assets/fonts/Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Flaticon";
        src: url("./assets/fonts/Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
    }
}
...
```

It compiles with no error, but no icon is showing. If I try to change the fonts path, then I have errors.

I display icons the same way I usually do:

```
<i class="flaticon-check"></i>
```

Comment: Hi, did you managed to solve this issue ? I've got the same I guess, compilation is good but fonts are not found on my browser

Comment: Not really. I ended up using a cdn. http://ionicons.com/. If you find a way, please let me know.

Comment: I found something : by importing _fonts.sass in main.js, the fonts are loadings.

Comment: Please, can you show how you do that? I can't wrap my head around that. How do you import it?